# Segmentation Fault in SSL_CTX_new

Tags: c, unix, ssl, openssl, segmentation-fault

I am trying to connect as a client over `SSL` and am seeing some strange behavior.
I am getting an intermittent segmentation fault inside `SSL_CTX_new` when trying to create a new `SSL` context. It should also be noted that this is a `fCGI demon`, and only seems to have an issue when running as such. If I run it as a standalone `cgi` application, the issue seems to disappear.

Looking into the core file, this is what I see:

> splint(??, ??) at 0xd03c36f4
>      malloc_y(0x4c, 0x0, 0x9e, 0x0, 0x20062240, 0x170, 0x0, 0x0) at 0xd03c5bcc
>      malloc_common_81_64(??) at 0xd03512b8
>      mem.default_malloc_ex() at 0xd0b0f784
>      CRYPTO_malloc_24_10() at 0xd0b101c8
>      ssl_cert.ssl_cert_new() at 0xd6f86084
>      ssl_lib.SSL_CTX_new() at 0xd6f83084

Has anyone run into something similar? A search of previous questions turned up some discussions of `SSL_CTX_new` returning `NULL`, but no reports of segmentation faults.

Here's the function I'm using to create the new context:

```
SSL_CTX* newSSLContext(char* keyfile, char* password) {  
   SSL_METHOD *meth;  
   SSL_CTX *ctx;  
   if (!bio_err) {  
      SSL_library_init();  
      SSL_load_error_strings();  
      bio_err = BIO_new_fp(stderr, BIO_NOCLOSE);  
   }  
   signal(SIGPIPE, sigpipe_handle);  
   meth = SSLv23_method();  
   ctx = SSL_CTX_new(meth);  
   if (!(SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file(ctx, keyfile))) {  
      err("Can't read certificate file");  
      return NULL;  
   }  
   pass = password;  
   SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb(ctx, password_cb);  
   if (!(SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, keyfile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM))) {  
      err("Can't read key file");  
      return NULL;
   }  
   if (!(SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, keyfile, 0))) {  
      err("Can't read CA list");  
      return NULL;  
   }  
   return ctx;  
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the call to `SSLv23_method()` does **not** return `NULL`?

Comment: @alk: Good catch. I have since added checks for 'NULL' after 'ctx' and 'meth' are set. 'SSLv23_method()' returns fine, and I'm dying in 'SSL_CTX_new()' pretty consistently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short of a good solution. I've resorted to switching to libcurl for my SSL needs. This seems to streamline the code I actually have to write.

Answer (score 4):

Are you initializing the `bio_err` variable to NULL? If you don't call `SSL_library_init` before `SSL_CTX_new`,  you will segfault.

Comment: It appears that you are correct. On an initial pass through this code, 'bio_err' is 'NULL'. However, on subsequent passes 'bio_erro' is not NULL. I have removed the !bio_err check and run the program so that 'SSL_library_init()' is called every time. In this case, my code dies in 'SSL_library_init()' with a similar call through 'CRYPTO_malloc_24_10'.
I have also called 'ERR_remove_state(0)' and 'ERR_free_strings()' to the end of my SSL logic, so ensure that memory is cleaned up, but it does not seem to have had any effect.

Comment: `SSL_library_init` should only be called once.

Comment: Here's my dilemma, since I'm running as a 'fCGI' demon, the same pid will serve multiple requests. 'bio_err' is declared within the 'openSSL' framework, so I can only assume it's initialized to 'NULL'. On subsequent passes, if it's not 'NULL', I can skip the 'SSL_library_init()' but I still get a segementation fault.